# Not able to write to directory despite correct permission and group

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, root

Have been strugling with a wordpress-virus attacking and Writing files in one of my sites. One strange thing i noticed is that even with the root user i am not able to write to the directory. The directory is 755. Trying to write to Another directory with same permissions works.

```
root@console:/var/www/clients/client3/web22# whoami
root

root@console:/var/www/clients/client3/web22# groups root
root : root

root@console:/var/www/clients/client3/web22# ls -alh
total 29M
drwxr-xr-x 8 root  root    4.0K Sep 13 11:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root  root    4.0K Oct  5 15:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 web22 client3 4.0K Feb 18  2016 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root    4.0K Nov  2  2016 log
drwxr-x--x 7 web22 client3 4.0K Oct  5 14:54 web

root@console:/var/www/clients/client3/web22# touch test
touch: cannot touch ‘test’: Permission denied

root@console:/var/www/clients/client3/web22# mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Permission denied
```

Heres a go on Another folder with same permissions, same user and same machine:

```
root@console:/var/www/clients/client5/web24# ls -lah
total 32K
drwxr-xr-x 8 root  root    4.0K Oct  5 15:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root    4.0K Mar 24  2016 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 web24 client5 4.0K Feb 19  2016 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root    4.0K Nov  2  2016 log
drwxr-x--x 9 web24 client5 4.0K Mar 19  2016 web

root@console:/var/www/clients/client5/web24# touch test
root@console:/var/www/clients/client5/web24# rm test
```

Why am I not able to write anything to the folder /var/www/clients/client3/web22 and is there anything else than Groups and users that can deny write to a directory?

**Edit - Adding necessary information:**

```
root@console:/var/www/clients/client3/web22# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.16.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Debian 4.8.4-1) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u1 (2016-09-03)

root@console:/var/www/clients/client3# lsattr
----i--------e-- ./web22
-------------e-- ./web13

root@console:/var/www/clients/client3# lsattr web22
-------------e-- web22/cgi-bin
-------------e-- web22/web
-------------e-- web22/log


root@console:/var/www/clients/client3# getfacl web22
# file: web22
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

root@console:/var/www/clients/client3# getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Comment: Are you using `acls` or `selinux` or something like that?  Those could also affect permissions

Comment: I must check to be sure, but I do not think so. This is a clean Ubuntu 16 setup. AFAIK Ubuntu does not ship with either.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1256509/edit) your question to include the output of `lsattr` on the `web22` directory?

Comment: Ubuntu enables AppArmor by default since 7.10. Run `aa-status` to query its status.

Comment: I was misinformed. This is not a Ubuntu setup. Instead its a Debian. Checked for acls and it is installed, I included some output from getfacl in my edit above.

Comment: @eric-renouf Does the "i" in ----i--------e-- from lsatr have anything to do with this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i` in the attr list means that file has been marked as "immutable" so that's why you can't change it.  You can remove that if you want with `chattr -i .`

From the [man page for `chattr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr):

> A file with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data can be written to the file. Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

Comment: Perfect! Will that have any affect on anything else? And how come only this directory has been set? Is there anything that usually set this flag and is it normal behaviour?

Comment: I don't know of anything that would automatically set it, and of course it's usually a good idea to know why something was done before you undo it.  Perhaps someone who was previously working with that site had a reason for enabling that flag?

Comment: Thats the thing. I am the only administrator of this machine. And just a week ago i was able to write a tar-file to the directory in backup purposes. Removed some files yesterday and wanted to do Another backup but were denied. Starting to get worried that the setup has been compromised somehow. Can anything else than physical acces or ssh do this? Its a webserver with mail and dns. Lately just this site "web22" have had some strange behaviour - new files appearing in the directory etc. Seems like someone gotten an tty into the machine over www or scripts inside the directory.

Comment: New files appearing sure sounds like a big warning.  Depending on what sort of CGI scripts or similar are available on the machine, those could end up providing a reverse shell to run commands, or if someone has compromised something else about the site they may have been able to get a shell other than through ssh or physical access.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much. This specific site is a Wordpress installation. And I Think the owner has installed some bad themes or such. Fortunately Everything is separated by users and Groups so whatever runs inside / from that site should be contained there. Found a very suspicious string containing a urldecode of 1.225 characters inside the "functions.php" file. commented out that line and hope it keeps whoever or whatever that was out. Its for Another post, but this is how the string looks like: $O00OO0=urldecode("%6E1%7A%62%2F%6D%615%5C%76%740%69 and continues. Again, T.Y very much!